# What is Google app script URLFetch service response size limit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

I'm writing a `Google App Script` for a Google spreadsheet and I'm facing a problem with the `URLFetch` service.

I'm requesting an external service and I **sometimes** receive an empty response. The external service is pretty stable and must return something, at least an error message if something wrong happens.

But I sometimes receive an empty response, just nothing.

I can only solve this by modifying the request so the expected response should be less in size, and this always fix the issue. Which makes me think its a response size limitation.

I doubt its a random problem because rerunning the script again to issue the same request always fails, unless, as I said, I modify the request to receive a response less in size.

But [on Google's quota page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), I can't find a **clear** answer to my question.

At the time of asking this question, I'm facing a problem of reading a response that is supposed to be around `14.1 KB`. I knew the size by running the request manually on my browser.

Does anyone know if there is a limitation and what exactly is it ?

Comment: Hmm, 14.1KB seems very small for this to be a size issue. For example, you can see on the examples at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external that the URL fetch is usable with Youtube to manipulate video feeds. Not exactly the same I know, but I would expect that to handle more than 14.1kb. Do you always get a response code of 200, even with these failed fetches? Is it possible there's a rate limit at play here? Have you tried exponential backoff? May be unrelated, but worth asking I think.

Comment: I haven't checked the response code, I will and get back to you. What do you mean "if there is a limit at play " ? I haven't tried an exponential backoff.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a rate limit on the application that your pulling the data from, and if you're hitting this limit and thus getting an empty response (you shouldn't get an empty response, it should fail instead, but you never know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the limit is 10MB. It is definitely larger than 14.1KB, an application I developed (http://www.blinkreports.com) routinely receives responses in excess of 1MB.

Comment: Based on my question, your answer is definitely correct because I tried POSTing my requests and it worked with responses up to 1 MB. Only then I found that my issue is when I issue GET requests with URLs larger than about 2 KB. Although Google clearly states that the URL length limit is 8 KB, I'm facing a much less limit ! I'll have to experiment more on that. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the same limits apply for UrlFetch in Google Apps script as in App Engine.. these limits apply :

- request size 10 megabytes
- response size    32 megabytes

see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/#Java_Quotas_and_limits